# U-net: how to improve accuracy of multiclass segmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I have been using U-nets for a while now, and notice that in most of my applications, it generates an over-estimation surrounding a specific class.

For example, here's a grayscale image:

[image]

And a manual segmentation of 3 classes (lesion [green], tissue [magenta], background [all else]):

[image]

The issue I notice on prediction (over-estimation at boundaries):

[image]

The typical architecture used looks something like this:

```
def get_unet(dim=128, dropout=0.5, n_classes=3):

 inputs = Input((dim, dim, 1))
 conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
 conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
 pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

 conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
 conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
 pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

 conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
 conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
 pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

 conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
 conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
 conv4 = Dropout(dropout)(conv4)
 pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

 conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
 conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
 conv5 = Dropout(dropout)(conv5)

 up6 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
 conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up6)
 conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)

 up7 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
 conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up7)
 conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)

 up8 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
 conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up8)
 conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)

 up9 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
 conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up9)
 conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)

 conv10 = Conv2D(n_classes, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', ker nel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
 conv10 = Reshape((dim * dim, n_classes))(conv10)

 output = Activation('softmax')(conv10)

 model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[output])

 return model
```

Plus:

```
mgpu_model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'], sample_weight_mode='temporal')  

open(p, 'w').write(json_string)

model_checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(f, save_best_only=True)
reduce_lr_cback = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
    patience=5, verbose=1,
    min_lr=0.05 * 0.0001)

h = mgpu_model.fit(train_gray, train_masks,
                   batch_size=64, epochs=50,
                   verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2, sample_weight=sample_weights,
                   callbacks=[model_checkpoint, reduce_lr_cback])
```

**My Question:**
Do you have any insight or suggestion on how to change either the architecture or hyperparameters to mitigate the over-estimation? This could include even using a different architecture that may be better at more precise segmentation. (Please note I already do class balancing/weighting to compensate for imbalances in class frequency)

Comment: maybe increase kernel from 3 to 5 and replace `UpSampling2D` to `Conv2DTranspose`

Comment: thanks @Kenan - would increasing the kernel have the opposite effect? ie. from a 128px image, wouldn't a larger convolution kernel too drastically remove spatial information?

Comment: hmm...I might be mixing those up; however the only way to know is to try it out. Let me know how it does. I still stand with replacing `UpSampling2D` to `Conv2DTranspose`

Comment: sounds good, I've run a few test with little change... do you have a suggestion for `kernel` and `stride` in the Conv2DTranspose?

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with various loss functions instead of cross entropy. For multi-class segmentation, you can try:

- generalized dice loss
- dice loss (summed across all classes)
- [categorical focal loss](https://github.com/umbertogriffo/focal-loss-keras/blob/master/losses.py)
- [boundary loss](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.07032)

The winner of brats 2018 used autoencoder regularization (https://github.com/IAmSuyogJadhav/3d-mri-brain-tumor-segmentation-using-autoencoder-regularization). You could try this as well. The idea in that paper is that the model is also learning how to better encode the features in the latent space, and that helps the model with segmentation somehow.